# Format USB Drive with FAT on Mac with different Allocation Unit Size

Tags: hard-drive, mac, usb, format, allocation-unit

I've been asked to format a USB Drive with a larger Allocation Unit Size than the default.  I'm using a Mac, Snow Leopard.  In Disk Utility, I am unable to see anything to do with Allocation Unit Size.  A bit of Googling suggests it might be called Cluster Size, but I can't see anything for that, either.  Does anyone know if it's possible to format a drive with FAT and use a larger than default Allocation Unit Size / Cluster Size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this from a command line using the `newfs_msdos` command. For example:

> #> newfs_msdos -F 32 -V somevolumename /dev/youdiskdevice

The command takes many arguments that you may want to explore.. `-c` cluster-size for example.

I am sure you could google around for newfs_msdos for some usage examples and also `man newfs_msdos`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, that does appear to have the answer, thanks.  The -c option says "Sectors per cluster.  Acceptable values are powers of 2 in the range 1 through 128", and I had been expecting a size in bytes... so if I was to want 32KB (the value that I've been told to use), what value do I choose?  15, since 2^15 is 32,768...?

Comment: does not work for me. The disk hangs after typing this and 30 minutes pass, nothing happens. I don't know if it is formatting, but 30 minutes is too much.

Answer (score 8):

For example to format FAT32 with 64kb allocation unit size:

> sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -c 128 -v VOLUMEID /dev/yourdiskdevice

with 32kb allocation unit size should be use 64 cluster size:

> sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -c 64 -v VOLUMEID /dev/yourdiskdevice

Comment: Because -c option means "number of sectors per cluster" with a 512bytes sector size you need 128 sectors to have 64kb allocation unit size. (just explaining the result  )

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that I had to `unmount` the disk in order to format the card. So I looked around to find an answer for the different errors, when all I actually needed to do was

```
diskutil unmount /dev/disk(the ident number)
```

I had to format my micro SD for a sports cam and the "cluster" size was wrong. I tried the `-c 32` first, no joy. `-c 64` Bingo!